# Dynamic HashMap in Android for search

Tags: java, android, dynamic, hashmap

We were designing an android app for a competition. I was trying to improvise on the features by trying to have a temporary cache on the app. I was going to use HashMap for this purpose. However, I was wondering if there is any special way of creating dynamic hashMap. If yes, please let me know as I am a java noob.(Google did not help much) As of now, i am using the normal declaration for hashMap.(I'm sure that's not right though).

Comment: hashmap is already Dynamic ....What you want ?

Comment: Uh, I meant more like, how can i make sure that when the application is turned off, the memory is freed up. So I don't really know if in Java, it clears up the entire memory everytime the program is stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM takes care of memory once an application as been terminated.  Memory will automatically be free'd up after you exit the program.

Now, if you want to dump the hash map to a file, that's a different story, since HashMap implements Serializable, you can dump the object bytes to a file before the app exits, and load it back in when it starts back up.

Decent write up on Serialization:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: that was helpful. can I assume the same about lists? Do ArrayLists also automatically free the memory? What I don't want happening is, there should be a clean memory every time the app loads.

Comment: Unless you dig down into the operation of the JVM (highly unrecommended), you shouldn't have to worry about memory allocation.  It's a managed language, so the memory is managed for you through the use of garbage collection, etc.